# mandriva bind configure openssl not found

Tags: bind, openssl, linux

I'm having some difficulties installing bind on a mandriva 2010.2 server. When I run `./configure` I get an error saying that it cannot find `include/openssl/opensslv.h` relative to the path of the openssl directory.

I personally installed openssl using `urpmi openssl` and runned again `./configure --with-openssl=/usr/lib/openssl` but this time it says given path is not a directory. After I did some checkings it turns out it wasn't a directory indeed. After that, I found that I have a directory called `openssl-1.0.0a` inside `/usr/lib`, but it does not have any `include` dir inside it.

`file /usr/lib/openssl` says this is a LSB executable, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped.

What is the problem ? Where should I find the path that bind is searching for in order to finish the installation ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed again openssl, this time from sources, and after I gave the new path to bind config it installed successfully :)